# just a part of base64 decoded image is displaying

Tags: android, html, image, base64

I want to post a bitmap to server by decoding base64. But after decoding I can display just a part of image(some top of image). How can I solve this problem?
I won't write codes for posting because they are work succesfully. In bitmapToString function I can get base64 strings and I try to display them, but I can see only a part of images.

Codes:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST) && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Bitmap bitmap = scaleBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath), 512,512,360);

            bitMapToString(bitmap); //this function logs the base64 strings
        }
    }
}

public String bitmapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String result = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.d("BitmapToString",result); //here I get base64 strings
    return result;
}

public Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bm, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, int ifSquareMaxValue) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();

    if(maxWidth>width && maxHeight>height)
        return bm;
    if (width > height) {
        float ratio = (float) width / maxHeight;
        width = maxHeight;
        height = (int)(height / ratio);
    } else if (height > width) {
        float ratio = (float) height / maxWidth;
        height = maxWidth;
        width = (int)(width / ratio);
    } else {
        height = ifSquareMaxValue;
        width = ifSquareMaxValue;
    }

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, true);
}
```

for example, a base64 string of an image is this: (from bitmapToString function line: Log.d("BitmapToString",result);)

```
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
```

when I use use in img tag display like this:
http://kombers.org/a.html

Comment: `to post a bitmap to server by decoding base64`. ??? What are you doing? Dont understand a word. Please first tell what your code should do before we look at the code.

Comment: `an result base64 string of an image is this:`. Where and how did you get that string?

Comment: `Log.d("BitmapToString",result);`. If you took the string from the LogCat printed by this Log statement then you did wrong. Log only prints the first piece of long strings.

Comment: I edited question.When I get from mysql database, the result is same. LogCat prints all of string.

Comment: I am very sorry. I found the problem. I you told me LogCat doesn't show all of the string and I made type of table column text, now when I made mediumtext, problem got solve.